# Push an attribute to all JSON objects in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

In javascript, I have an array of JSON objects;

```
var myArr = [{'attr1':1, 'attr2':2}, {'attr1':3, 'attr2':4}, {'attr1':5, 'attr2':6}]
```

I want to add another attribute 'attr3' to ALL JSON OBJECTS in this array. How to achieve this without using a loop construct with myArr[x].attr3='val'?

My desired end result is;

```
[{'attr1':1, 'attr2':2, 'attr3':'val'}, {'attr1':3, 'attr2':4, 'attr3':'val'}, {'attr1':5, 'attr2':6, 'attr3':'val'}]
```

Comment: what is a loop construct?

Comment: You can't do this without a loop. Even if you use an array function like forEach() there is still an implicit loop iterating over the elements. Also, there is no JSON in the code shown, you just have "objects", not "JSON objects".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for editing every element in an array.

```js
var myArr = [{ 'attr1': 1, 'attr2': 2 }, { 'attr1': 3, 'attr2': 4 }, { 'attr1': 5, 'attr2': 6 }];

myArr = myArr.map( function(e) {
    e.attr3 = 'val';
    return e;
} );

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(myArr, 0, 4) + "</pre>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for iterating through the array.

```js
var myArr = [{ 'attr1': 1, 'attr2': 2 }, { 'attr1': 3, 'attr2': 4 }, { 'attr1': 5, 'attr2': 6 }];

myArr.forEach(function (a) {
    a.attr3 = 'val';
});
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(myArr, 0, 4) + "</pre>");
```